# Data update from File Geodatabase to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, file-geodatabase

We are using PostGIS to serve our geographic data by WMTS with GeoServer, and the origin data are produced with ArcMap (using the file geodatabase format).

We use the ArcMap database connection tool to export data to the database.  However all the data take up almost 20GB, it may cost 10 hours to export all of them to the database.

Now once there are some modification of the origin data, how to update the database effectively?

It is not a wise option to export them all again.

Comment: To you log the modifications? Like editor-tracking or some other method.

Comment: No ,we have not used any editor tracking tool at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esri already has a mechanism for synchronizing distributed updates -- [enterprise geodatabase replication](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/replication-types.htm) (check-out/check-in or one-way child-to-parent).

It's also possible to identify changes using [Editor Tracking](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/enabling-editor-tracking.htm) and write scripts to transmit inserts and updates (deletes would be trickier, but still possible).

Finally, you can write your own scripts to manage distributed editing (which would likely involve structural changes to every table to facilitate change detection).

Given the apparent lack of an ArcGIS Server license, I would recommend you start by enabling Editor Tracking (both inserted_on and updated_on),  If you want to track deletes, you'll need to make sure you have a reliable perfect hash key column (like a UUID/GUID) so that "missing" fields can be discovered.

Comment: Yes,we do have a uuid for each  feature,but we do not known how to enable the edit tracking.

Comment: Writing Answers on a phone is a PITA. It just took a bit to identify the links.

Comment: Sorry,I miss that. I will have a try.